# Looking for Distinct Solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 100$ Given Certain Conditions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How many distinct solutions to the equation does the following have?

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4  = 100$$ such that $x_1 \in \{0,1,2,... 10 \}, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \{0,1,2,3,...\}$

My attempt: Ordinarily if the range of all the $x_i$s were the set of natural numbers including zero, I could just do $_{103}C_3$. However since $x_1$ is bound from $0$ to $10$ inclusive, I can't do that. What I attempted was to set $x_1$ to each value from $0$ to $10$ and then take the summation of all the distinct solutions for each x_1.

Hence,

$$\sum^{10}_{i=0}(_{102-i}C_2)$$
So for each value of $x_1$ I find how many distinct solutions to the equation

$$x_2 + x_3 + x_4  = 100 - x_1$$
there are and then sum them together.

Is this the right approach? It feels kinda awkward to me? Is there a more efficient option?

Comment: You might try dropping the constraint on $x_1$ and counting the solutions to  that problem.  Then see if you can find the number of solutions in which $x_1 > 10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to solve the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 100 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the restriction that $x_1 \leq 10$.

Since a particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of $100$ ones, there are 
$$\binom{100 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{103}{3}$$
solutions of the equation in the nonnegative integers since we must choose which three of the $103$ positions required for $100$ ones and three addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

From these, we must subtract those solutions in which $x_1 > 10$.

Let's count the number of solutions that violate the restriction that $x_1 \leq 10$.  Suppose $x_1 > 10$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 11$.  Then $x_1'$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 11$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 100\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 89 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{89 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{92}{3}$$
solutions.

Hence, the number of nonnegative integer solutions of equation 1 that satisfy the restriction that $x_1 \leq 10$ is

$$\binom{103}{3} - \binom{92}{3}$$

Comment: @nmasanta Thank you for fixing the error.

Comment: It's Matheus Douglas, who first notice this, I just improve his edit. Take care in next time.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is correct. You just need to do:

$$x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 100-x_1$$

So, we have:

$$\sum_{x_1 = 0}^{10} \binom{102-x_1}{2}$$

We know that:

$$\sum_{k=m}^{n} \binom{k}{m} = \binom{n+1}{m+1}$$

Hence:

$$\sum_{x_1 = 0}^{10} \binom{102-x_1}{2} = \sum_{k=2}^{102} \binom{k}{2} - \sum_{k=2}^{91} \binom{k}{2} = \binom{103}{3} - \binom{92}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for fixing the error in my answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$k$-combination with repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition). When I write as $_{n}H_{k}=\mathrm{}_{n+k-1}C_k$ instead of $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$, the following is true:

$$\begin{align}\frac{(n+k)!}{k!n!}&=\mathrm{}_{n+k}C_{k}=\mathrm{}_{n+1}H_k\\
&=\mathrm{}_n H_k+\mathrm{}_{n+1}H_{k-1}\\
&=\mathrm{}_{n}H_k+\mathrm{}_{n}H_{k-1}+\cdots+\mathrm{}_{n}H_1+\mathrm{}_{n+1}H_0.\end{align}$$

Therefore, the result you are looking for is $\mathrm{}_4H_{100}-\mathrm{}_4H_{89}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what _nH_k is representing, could you explain it intuitively?

Comment: See the link in the answer. That's the number of cases in which $k$ objects out of $n$ objects are selected with repetitions allowed.

Comment: The link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets also helps. The expression you used $_{102-i}C_2$ means the same as $_3H_{100-i}$.